# Is it possible to give fix score for specific field search in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to give fix score based on every field match. for e.g one field matched then increment score for document by 1 , second field matched then increment document score by 1, so if there are one fields matched the score would be 1 if two fields matched then score would be 2 and so on...

Answer (score 2):

The best tool for modifying the _score value of a query is the function_score query.

Elasticsearch actually offers many methods for calculating the score for each match. You can use a custom_score query along with a script to access the value of a particular numeric field. Consider this statement:

```
"script" : "_score * doc['my_numeric_field'].value"
```

Here, we are giving weight to the value of my_numeric_field by multiplying it with the default _score. You could also use the custom_filters_score_query, in which you apply filters to restrict the result set and then use a script or a boost to assign a score to any documents that match the filter. Similarly, you could apply the custom_boost_factor to any query to multiply the default score of that query with a boost value. In the 0.19.0 release of Elasticsearch, there is a new query that combines all of these into the function_score query.

Comment: Ok thank you for you answer, do we actually have to give _score in this ? because when using _score it might use the Elasticsearch algorithm for score and i want only specific i.e increment all by 1 for each match